# Proof that $rs = sr^{-1}$ in $D_{2n}$

Tags: group-theory, symmetry, dihedral-groups

In the group $D_{2n}$, we define $r$ to be a counterclockwise rotation by $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ and $s$ a reflection through a fixed line of symmetry. I'm trying to prove that
$$rs = sr^{-1}.$$

I can prove smaller cases, like $n=3,4,5$ by drawing the figures and performing the rotations or reflections in succession, but I cannot figure out how to prove this for an arbitrary $n$.

I'd appreciate any hints or direction on how to proceed.

Comment: The [tag:proof-explanation] tag is for when you have a proof that you want an explanation of.

Comment: @Shaun Sorry about that, and thank you for fixing it.

Comment: Label the vertices $1$ through $n$ and consider how the rotation and reflection operations act on them. This will define an injection to the group $S_n$ so you can examine the cycle decomposition. Do this for the small cases and see if you can generalize from there.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

The relation is the same as $(sr)^2=1$.  So it suffices to check that $sr$ is a reflection.

Drawing a picture makes it rather trivial: rotating a reflection gives another reflection (through the rotated axis).

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ denote the vertices of the $n$-gon ordered clockwise. If $a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_n$ denotes the $n$-gon before performing any symmetries, then we see that

$$
a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_n\mathop{\Rightarrow}^r a_n,a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{n-1}\tag1
$$
$$
a_n,a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{n-1}\mathop{\Rightarrow}^s a_n,a_{n-1},a_{n-2},\dots,a_1\tag2
$$
$$
a_n,a_{n-1},a_{n-2},\dots,a_1\mathop{\Rightarrow}^r a_1,a_n,a_{n-1},\dots,a_2\tag3
$$

By comparing the left hand side of (1) and the right hand side of (3), we see that the $rsr=s$, which gives the desired result.